# Php doesn't create session in webmatrix

Tags: php, session, session-variables, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

i'm started to use webmatrix and now iam using php starter site template.

in this template you cant login. i searched all codes than i found it doesnt create session. maybe it creates but dont pass to other pages.

if there is user(logon.php):

```
if ($statement->num_rows == 1)
{

    $statement->bind_result($uid,$uname);
    $statement->fetch();
    $_SESSION['userid']=$uid;
    $_SESSION['username']=$uname;
    echo $_SESSION['username']; // yes its printing username
    header ("Location: index.php");
}
```

check(header.php):

```
  if (logged_on())
    {
        echo '<li><a href="/logoff.php">Sign out</a></li>' . "\n";
    }
```

logged_on function:

```
function logged_on()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['userid']); //empty
}
```

Comment: have you used `session_start()` at top of every page? If not use it your problem will be solved. :)

Comment: i wrote it every page but still same :(

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
session_start();
```

on the top of the page